# How to prevent symfony 3 to rebuild routes when I edit a controller

Tags: php, symfony, caching, routes

I am working in a controller, the code that I change must stay here. The routes are defined as annotations in the controller.

So, maybe it is not the cause, but whenever I make a change to my code and refresh my page, the first refresh is very slow (the project is huge, many controllers).
After a first refresh, the next ones are quick. So I guess symfony detects the controller has changed and rebuilds the router cache.

This is painful.

How can I temporarily disable re-scanning the whole project for routes ?

Comment: Delay is caused by Symfony cache rebuilding in `dev` mode. You can switch to `prod` mode for example, it keeps cache as it is unless it is warmed up explicitly

Comment: @Flying well I still have to develop my app ...

Comment: I'll provide more information as an answer for the question

Comment: Did you find a solution?  Initialization times for me are 30-40 seconds which is a pain -.-

Answer (score 1):

Significant delays in `dev` environment are caused by container re-building. It is actually very good decision from Symfony developers because it allows you to focus on development itself and don't waste time trying to hunt mysterious bugs that will be actually caused by hidden incompatibilities between your code and container contents.

Simplest way to avoid automatic container re-building is to switch to `prod` environment where Symfony expects you to care about container by yourself. However in this case you will also lose a lot of other convenient tools that are provided by Symfony into `dev` environment.

There is also slightly harder alternative. Take a look at [`Kernel::initializeContainer()`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/848a83078cc4b3927d614c9497456193bf4f5cea/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php#L573) method, it is responsible for container initialization. As you can see from the code - Symfony checks if container is fresh. It is done by loading `.meta` files that resides in container and checking if all files listed in them are same as they was at a time of container building. Since this method is quite internal - it is not open for simple modifications but you can copy / paste it into your application's container and modify to match your needs. Of course you need to understand that this approach can't be treated as recommended way and unlikely supported by Symfony developers so you have to accept possible consequences, but still - it is possible to implement.

Comment: Hey, thank you. I know how SF container works, and I need it. I do not want to be in prod environment, I want to code in a dev environment, just as normal, just skip the router config reloading.

According to what you said I may delve into SF internal code, but that is a solution I'd like to avoid.

Thank you